# Show information based on users

Tags: django, view

I have a class called `Schedule` with a field (is this correct?) I've set using 
`admins = models.ManyToManyField(User)`. This field contains a list of users I can select multiples of.

In the view for the schedule, I show a bunch of information. I would like to show a couple additional things based on if the currently logged in user is included in the admins of that schedule being viewed.

Comment: BTW.. When I say View, I mean showing it in the template.  Not in the views.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Django philosophy, you should have your business logic within views and presentation logic in the template. So the computation if the logged user is among the admins should be done in a view, and if the user is, then what is displayed should be determined in the template. You can accomplish that by:

```
# views.py
def schedule(request, id):
    schedule = get_object_or_404(Schedule, pk=id)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        is_admin = schedule.admins.filter(pk=schedule.pk).exists()
    else:
        is_admin = False
    data = {
        'schedule': schedule,
        'is_admin': is_admin,
    }
    return render_to_response('template.html', data)

# template.html
{% if is_admin %}
    <p>You are an admin of the schedule!</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Sorry. You are not an admin of the schedule</p>
{% endif %}
```